# Jquery Nested Dynamically Created Droppables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to create a page where you can drag a droppable div (class spacing2) into a droppable div (class spacing1) and then drag controls into spacing2. I am able to drop the controls into spacing, but am unable to drop anything into spacing2.

http://jsfiddle.net/dan2012/FCT3m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the droppables to sortables and only have 1 of them enabled at a time.